# Using only 1 app server and no CDN, how to dynamically load heavy resources (ex: big images) for users from different parts of the world?

Tags: php, performance, mod-rewrite, load-balancing, cdn

I'm trying to find a way to dynamically load heavy resources (ex: big images) for users from different parts of the world, with the following limitations in mind:

1. I can have only 1 app server (instead of using load balancers connecting to multiple app servers).
2. But I can have multiple storage servers (running a web server), which simply store heavy static resources like pics/pdfs/videos.
3. I can not use commercial CDN (due to budget issues).

Currently I have two ideas:

1. On app server, using apache mod_rewrite rules to channel users from different ip to go to different storage servers.
2. Modify code in the app server (we are using PHP with cake framework), so the app server will render different resource URL depending on client users' IP.

**My question is, which one would you do and why? Or, would you recommend some other ways to achieve the result?**

Comment: If you can afford multiple storage servers, you should be able to afford some CDN. The base issue is that you will trade speed for performance, as either mod_rewrite and the app mod will cost resources at rendering time. I would opt for the mod_rewrite for being easier to implement.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! for me since I have to serve Chinese user, so the CDN is a bit more difficult to set up. Since Chinese gov. requires every website, as long as there is a domain name, you need to have "ICP" licence. We can apply it but just timing is an issue for us. Also we do not have Chinese legal entity, which is also required to apply ICP. For ex: https://www.amazonaws.cn/en/about-aws/china/

Comment: Well, all my force goes to you then. I still suggest the mod_rewrite, that should be easy to implement. Just condition it to your "big assets" folder and you're done.

Comment: There are some trick to load Images quickly on HTTP/1, you have to create multiple subdomain eg `sub.example.com` , `sub2.example.com` , `sub3.example.com` and point all subdomain to a one directory, with PHP Script you can use `rand(1,3)` function to generate random url, so Images will load faster. OR use HTTP/2!

Comment: simply having the url's to 'other' servers will reduce stress on yours, the browser will download them fine.

Answer (score -1):

Give a try to CloudFlare you can use the free plan that also will give you a valid certificate in case wan to use `https`, more info here:

https://www.cloudflare.com/plans/

If that still not possible, you could try to create your own `CDN` by using Nginx cache module, more details here:

https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/

Check the `Splitting the Cache Across Multiple Hard Drives` section, based on your hardware, servers could be an option:

```
proxy_cache_path /path/to/hdd1 levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache_hdd1:10m
                 max_size=10g inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;
proxy_cache_path /path/to/hdd2 levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache_hdd2:10m
                 max_size=10g inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;

split_clients $request_uri $my_cache {
              50%          "my_cache_hdd1";
              50%          "my_cache_hdd2";
}

server {
    # ...
    location / {
        proxy_cache $my_cache;
        proxy_pass http://my_upstream;
    }
}
```

Comment: That really doesn't fit the "no CDN" requirement in the question.

Comment: @ceejayoz should the CDN tag then be removed?